# Homebrew installation failed on OS X El Capitan. Uninstall won't work. How do I start over and reinstall?

Tags: install, macos, homebrew

I'm trying to install Homebrew. Running OS X 10.11.1. When installing, I got an error message. I now can't retrieve the output I got, but there were several "fatal" errors.

When trying to reinstall Homebrew, I get the following:

> It appears Homebrew is already installed. If your intent is to
>   reinstall you should do the following before running this installer
>   again:
>       ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall)"
>   The current contents of /usr/local are include lib .git

And when I follow those instructions by running the script it recommends, I get:

```
-e:100:in `realpath': No such file or directory - /usr/local/bin (Errno::ENOENT)
    from -e:100:in `realpath'
    from -e:100:in `<main>'
```

So how in the world do I perform a clean uninstall and reinstall?

Comment: is there anything in these folders :  `/usr/local/.git` and  `/usr/local/Cellar` ?

Answer (score 2):

Late answer, but I just ran into this issue myself.

This Github [issue](https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/44460) suggests the solution is to run `rm -rf /usr/local/.git`. I did that, but the issue persisted. I then deleted the `/usr/local/Homebrew` directory. That seemed to resolve things for me, and I could then re-run the install command OK.